# How to read the template partial specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, partial-specialization

Suppose the following declaration:

```
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate;
```

The following definition of the partial specialization seems to use the same letter `T` to refer to different types.

```
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate<T*> {};
```

For example, let's take a concrete instantiation:

```
MyTemplate<int *> c;
```

Now, consider again the above definition of the partial specialization:

```
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate<T*> {};
```

In the first part of this line (i.e. `template <typename T>`), `T` is `int *`. In the second part of the line (i.e. `MyTemplate<T*>`), `T` is `int`!

So, how is the definition of the partial specialization read?

Comment: Take `T *`, replace `T` with `int`, and you get `int *`.

Comment: It is similar to normal argument: the `a` in `int foo(int a)`, `void bar(int a)` and `void foobar(std::string&a)` are not the same.

Comment: I understand the effect of the definition. However, using the same letter for two different types in the same line of code does not make sense to me. It's like having `T(T)`, which gets resolved as `int *(int)`... I have edited the question to emphasize the point.

Comment: You're right. How do I read it?

Comment: `In the first part of this line (i.e. template <typename T>), T is int *,`. It isn't. What makes you think so? If you assume that `int*` in the invication is somehow mspped to that T, then no, it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read it like this:

1. The *primary template* says "`MyTemplate` is a class template with one type parameter":

   ```
   template <typename> struct MyTemplate;
   ```
2. The *partial specialization* says, "whenever there exists a type `T`"...

   ```
   template <typename T>
   ```

   ... such that a specialization of `MyTemplate` is requested for the type `T *`"...

   ```
   struct MyTemplate<T *>
   ```

   ... then use this alternative definition of the template.
3. You could also define *explicit specializations*. For example, could say "whenever the specialization is requested for type `X`, use this alternative definition:

   ```
   template <> struct MyTemplate<X> { /* ... */ };
   ```

Note that explicit specializations of class templates define types, wheras partial specializations define templates.

To see it another way: A partial class template specialization *deduces*, or *pattern-matches*, the structure of the class template arguments:

```
template <typename T> struct MyTemplate<T *>
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^
//       This is a new template        Argument passed to the original class
//                                     template parameter
```

The parameter names of this new template are matched structurally against the argument of the original class template's parameters.

Examples:

- `MyTemplate<void>`: The type parameter of the class template is `void`, and the primary template is used for this specialization.
- `MyTemplate<int *>`: The type parameter is `int *`. There exists a type `T`, namely `T = int`, such that the requested type parameter is `T *`, and so the definition of the partial specialization of the template is used for this specialization.
- `MyTemplate<X>`: The parameter type is `X`, and an explicit specialization has been defined for that parameter type, which is therefore used.

Answer (score 2):

The correct reading of the specialisation is as follows:

```
template <typename T> // a *type pattern* with a *free variable* `T` follows
struct MyTemplate<T*> // `T*` is the pattern
```

When the template is instantiated by `MyTemplate<int*>`, the argument is *matched* against the pattern, not the type variable list. Values of the type variables are then *deduced* from the match.

To see this more directly, consider a template with two arguments.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A;
```

and its specialisation

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A<T1*, T2*>;
```

Now you can write the latter as

```
template <typename T2, typename T1>
struct A<T1*, T2*>;
```

(the variable list order is reversed) and this is equivalent to the previous one. Indeed, order in the list is irrelevant. When you invoke `A<int*, double*>` it is deduced that `T1=int`, `T2=double`, regardless of the order of T1 and T2 in the template head.

Further, you can do this

```
template <typename T>
struct A<T*, T*>;
```

and use it in `A<int*, int*>`. It is now plainly clear that the type variable list has no direct correspondence with the actual template parameter list.

Note: the terms "pattern", "type variable", "type pattern matching" are not standard C++ terms. They are pretty much standard almost everywhere else though.

Comment: There seems to be a typo: it says T2 twice in the reversed  order.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
MyTemplate<int *> c;
```

Your confusion seems to come from assuming that the `int *` in `< >` somehow corresponds to the `T` in `template <typename T>`. It does not. In a partial specialisation (actually in every template declaration), the template parameter names are simply "free variable" (or perhaps "placeholder") names. The template arguments (`int *` in your case) don't directly correspond to these, they correspond to what is (or would be) in the `< >` following the template name.

This means that the `<int *>` part of the instantiation maps to the `<T*>` part of the partial specialisation. `T` is just a name introduced by the `template <typename T>` prefix. In the entire process, the `T` is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction. T should be read as T, T* is T*.

`template <typename T> struct MyTemplate<T*> {};`

"In the first part of this line (i.e. `template <typename T>`), T is int *."

No - in `template <typename T>` T is int, in `struct MyTemplate<T*> {};` T is also int.

"Note that when a partial specialization is used, a template parameter is deduced from the specialization pattern; the template parameter is not simply the actual template argument. In particular, for `Vector<Shape*>`, T is Shape and not Shape*." (Stroustrup C++, 4th ed, 25.3, p. 732.)